# Is the area of Suresnes safe?

Tags: safety, paris

I'm going to Paris next December/January with my girlfriend. It's out first time in Europe.

We take Hôtel Novotel Paris Suresnes Longchamp, by review on Trip Advisor and other sites it looks a safe and nice hotel.

I would like to know if tis area, specialy in winter and near the end of year festivals is a safe place for tourist the bus and metro to go to Paris center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safety is not an issue.

The problem is that you are far from the city center without a direct metro (maybe bus?) to where everything is; I don't think the night life is that great in the area.

There's a train (metro, I'm not certain), the L train that gets you to Saint Lazare Train Station in about 30 minutes.

The Saint Lazare Train Station is as good as any starting/end point for your daily visits to Paris.

There are also bus lines, but I can't navigate the RATP site well enough to help you.

Comment: Yep, public transit is pretty poor in that area. And what the maps does not necessarily tell you is that the hotel is at the foot of a pretty large hill (Mont St Valérien), and the train station is midway up the hill :-(

Comment: Tranks for the return! I search about the public transport aroud, this is going to be a bit tiring, and take about 40 minutes to go to center of city.